# HTML Generator: Convert HTML to PlainText and put in a TextBox using PHP

Tags: php, html, iframe

I would like to make a generator to get easy work in eBay description.
So i've created a page with some form input that send the value to a php page in the main page iframe.
Now I need to take the full HTML code and put in the iframe (naturally I get the full rendered page) and I need to view the source code, copy and put in the eBay html description.

**So, the question is:** Can I convert the HTML code as plain text and put in a textbox so I can easily copy using a button? I don't need a wysiwycg.

I've googled it but can't find a reasonable result.

According to your reply, here is the code now:

Page1.php

```
// It's only the page containing the form that must to pass variables
```

Page2.php

```
$html = file_get_contents('desc.php');

echo '<textarea readonly style="border:none;resize:none" rows="50" cols="116" value="'. $html .'"></textarea>';
```

Page3.php

```
// This is the file desc.php that must to be in plaintext
```

Now I get the plain text file but the variables aren't passed since i've stored them in session.

And the textbox displays only half of the file, not showing the `<link>` and `<style>` tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use file_get_contents

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/');


echo $homepage;
```

or

```
 echo "<td><input type='text' value='$homepage'/></td>";
```

or for i frame

```
<iframe> 
   <div inside frame>
      <$php echo $content; ?>
   </div>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, seems to be work, but the question now is, how can I pass some variables to the $homepage file without using cookies or sessions? I must to send the values via GET to the page whit file_get_content and then display the final page code

Comment: Maybe it's confusing, i need to replace some string, like images url and something else with the forms input values, so if i get the content of the page it will retrieve the $variable as plain text instead of replace values

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments, but i see that this don't write down the <style> tag with css that is on the tag and the <link rel> css tags, this is very strange cause in theory it must to read all the file. At the moment seems that only half of the file is in the textarea and the strange thing is that is the second part of the file. Other thing it append an "> at the end of the text that seems to be the closing of the textarea tag.

Comment: I see only now your comment ... there are a lot of questions.. just a suggestion if the question you have posted  is solved . is better post the other question like separated question .. in this way .. all the SO communty can help you and not only me.. ..

Comment: thanks for the reply, i was updating the question but you're right, i will create another one thread.

Comment: Ok ..  is right .. and may be i can help you also in the  other question good work..